# pf firewall blocks raspbian apt-get update

Tags: networking, macos, firewall, apt-get, pf

I am connecting my raspberry pi 3(raspbian stretch) to my Macpro(10.13.2; High Sierra) to 802.3 ethernet port which is a part of bridged adapter (`bridge100`) using Internet Share feature. Internet interface on mac is `en2` (wireless).

Although, I can ping `google.com` or `mirrordirector.raspbian.org`, when I try to update packages, apt-get hangs forever:

```
# apt-get update
0% [Connecting to mirrordirector.raspbian.org (93.93.128.193)] [Connecting to archive.raspberrypi.org (93.93.130.104)]
```

When I disable pf firewall on the mac, it starts working.
My pf rules are the following:

```
LAN="bridge100"
WLAN="en2"

dns="53"
ntp="123"

set fingerprints "/etc/pf.os"
set skip on lo
set block-policy drop

set ruleset-optimization basic
set optimization normal
set timeout { tcp.established 600, tcp.closing 60 }
scrub in all no-df fragment reassemble
antispoof log quick for { lo $LAN $WLAN }


block all
block in log quick from no-route to any

pass in quick on { $LAN $WLAN } proto { udp tcp } from any to any port $dns keep state
pass in quick proto udp from any port 67 to any port 68
pass in proto udp from any to port $ntp

pass in inet proto icmp from 10.8.0.0/24
pass in inet proto icmp from 192.168.1.0/24
pass in inet proto icmp from 192.168.2.0/24
pass in inet proto icmp from 172.16.42.0/24

pass out all
```

What rule should I use to allow `apt-get update`. I thought `pass out all` will do it, but seems like I don't completely understand pf firewall. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, finally I've figured this out.
The problem was complex.

1 - I had the following redirect rules which I was not aware of:

```
rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to any port 80 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8080
rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to any port 443 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8443
```

So I commented them because apt-get uses port 80 (and probably 443)

2 - Main thing. When ticking **Internet Sharing** checkbox in **Preferences**, MacOS dynamically adds the following pf anchors:

```
nat-anchor "com.apple.internet-sharing" all
rdr-anchor "com.apple.internet-sharing" all

scrub-anchor "com.apple.internet-sharing" all fragment reassemble
anchor "com.apple.internet-sharing" all
```

Run `sudo pfctl -sa` to make sure that those anchors are included.
If not, then just untick and then tick again **Internet Sharing** checkbox in MacOS system **Preferences**.